# Make uploaded file public in wordpress media library

Tags: php, wordpress

I've kind of social networking wordpress site and users use wordpress's native upload script to upload images.

Is there anyway i can make some images accessible to all users. Right now they only see images uploaded by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:
This worked

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'devplus_wpquery_where' );
function devplus_wpquery_where( $where ){
global $current_user;

if( is_user_logged_in() ){
     // logged in user, but are we viewing the library?
     if( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && ( $_POST['action'] == 'query-attachments' ) ){
        // here you can add some extra logic if you'd want to.
        $where .= 'OR post_parent="6968"';
                  //OR ID='3783' // OR post_author= "34"
    }
}

return $where;
}
```

"Where" can be edited as per the need.